# Casting to a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, vector, casting

I have a vector of shared pointers of a pure virtual class IObserver (observers), the vector is a class which inherits IObserver. There is also a second class which inherits IObserver, HomeOwner. I want to cast Homeowner objects to the observers vector, so I can send them to the functions in SecurityStatus but not sure how I go about it. I'd like to do it behind the scenes rather than in the main program. The declaration for both is below.
Thanks!

```
        #pragma once

#include "IObserver.h"
#include "HouseSecurity.h"
#include "SensorInfo.h"

#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// concrete observer
class HomeOwner : public IObserver{
    SensorInfo currentSensorState;  
    string myName;
    string myPhoneNumber;
    string myEmail;
    HouseSecurity &house;   

public:
    void Update();
    void New();
    HomeOwner(string, string, string); 
};

#pragma once

#include "IObserver.h"
#include "HomeOwner.h"

#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
// subject

class SecurityStatus{
    vector <shared_ptr<IObserver>> observers;
public:
    void AttachObserver(shared_ptr<IObserver>); 
    void DetachObserver(shared_ptr<IObserver>);
    void NotifyObservers(); 
};
```

Comment: You need to create a brand new vector of pointers to IObserver and populate it with suitably cast elements of Homeowners vector. This is true for any kind of pointer and any kind of container.

Comment: How are you getting the `Homeowner` objects? To put them in the vector they need to be in a `shared_ptr` and then it should just compile.

Comment: Having said that, I don't see where your code needs to cast a vector of anything to a vector of anything else. Individual `shared_ptr<HomeOwner>` values can be passed to `AttachObserver` and `DetachObserver` without any problem, no explicit cast is necessary.